# How to check if EarPods are fake or not?

Tags: iphone, ear-phones

With iPhone, MacBook we have serial numbers etc. So it is possible to call support and to ask.

How can we check EarPods?

Comment: Do you mean AirPods?  What makes you suspicious?

Comment: I mean EarPods with Lightning Connector. Price some like 8-10 US dollars or euro.

Comment: It’s a poor device to go through the effort to try and copy for so little return, but if you’re unsure, buy from a reputable seller like directly from Apple

Comment: @Allan, I have asked some other question :) How to check if you already have it. Maybe its not possible at all or someone know any articles, advices etc. hot to check it. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has a [page to assist in verifying authenticity](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204308) for *some* of their products.

For EarPods, there's no easy way to check.

A few years ago, someone on LinkedIn [wrote a nice article with pictures](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-distinguish-fake-apple-earpod-from-real-one-nicole-ji/) to help people identify real products vs fake.

It comes down to quality of materials and workmanship.  If you look at the pictures and explanations in that link, you can easily see the type of quality Apple puts into the design and manufacture of their products. Use this only as a guide for things to look for.  They're not the only ways to spot a fake but it's a good start.

For example:

> **Check the bass holes in the EarPod (Clearest Way)**
>
> The OEM EarPods will conduct an airflow to the bass holes at the
>   bottom of it which be designed for better bass sound. If you cover
>   these holes with your fingers, less bass music can be heard.
>
> For fake ones, the “bass holes” are just for “decorating” purposes.
>   [image]

As mentioned in the comments, the best way to ensure you have a genuine product is to buy directly from Apple or a licensed reseller.

Answer (score -2):

1. You purchase your AirPods from an official Apple  retailer or of course an Apple Store....they are genuine Apple’s AirPods.
2. If you purchase them from an unofficial shop or someone give them to you or....ets.  Then all you have to do is pair them with tour iPhone or iPad through settings-Bluetooth-open AirPods case -press the pair button at the back of the case until pods are paired with iPhone/iPad. Then go to general-about-scroll down and you’ll see AirPods.
   Press AirPods and you’ll see data as: MANUFACTURER 
   MODEL NUMBER 
   SERIAL NUMBER 
   FIRMWARE VERSION 
   HARDWARE VERSION

Email apple support // go to an Apple store and give them those data ...they will verify if AirPods are genuine or fake or stolen ets.

Comment: Thank you. My question was not about AirPods. It has nothing to do with bluetooth.

Comment: I have not downvoted you.